# How to open new window when user clicks specific item in listbox with Python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

So I have many items in listbox and I want when user clicks on a certain item in the listbox, it should display the corresponding window. So for example, if the user clicks the first item in the listbox, it should display `window_1`, if the user clicks the second item it should display `window_2` and so on...

How can I achieve that with tkinter?

Comment: Have you read through tkinter documentation or worked through any tutorials? There are many examples on the internet for creating new windows, and many examples of how to respond to a double-click. What part of this problem do you need help with?

Comment: @BryanOakley The part of the problem I am concerned about is how can I can create unique windows for each item without creating n amount of functions for n amount of items in list.

Comment: I recommend you show an example of what you've tried, so we can see why you are having problem creating unique windows for each item.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well, I've solved the problem and posted it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've decided to use menu button for this task and solved the problem. This is how I did it:

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

mb = tk.Menubutton(root, text="   Answers   ")
mb.menu = tk.Menu(mb)
mb['menu'] = mb.menu
mb.pack()


def answers_message(text):
    t = tk.Toplevel()
    message = tk.Message(t, text=text)
    message.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=50, pady=50)


repetition = int(input("How many repetitions: "))
messages = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
for i in range(repetition):
    action_with_arg = partial(answers_message, messages[i])
    ans_label = "Answer {}".format(i)
    mb.menu.add_command(label=ans_label, command=action_with_arg)

root.mainloop()
```